# How to generate database script without replication data in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication, sql-scripts

I have two server in two areas "WAN" : "distributed system". 
I applied a merge replication for these two servers (Microsoft Sql Server 2008 R2). 
Now I'd like to generate the database script "Schema and Data", without replication data informations (rowguid column, ...) to run in a third local server (development server)?

how can I generate my script? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use backup and restore.  When doing the restore to your development server exclude the KEEP_REPLICATION switch.  This will ensure that no replication metadata will be restored.